# zsh: permission denied: gam

Tags: macos, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am using ZSH on macOS 10.12 with Oh My ZSH installed.

I recently installed [GAM](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM) on my computer using the provided install script `bash <(curl -s -S -L https://git.io/install-gam)`

The script installs the command line tool `gam` to `~/bin/gam/gam`, which is in my `PATH`.

However, when trying to execute any `gam` command in ZSH, I get the following:

```
➜  ~ gam info user
zsh: permission denied: gam
```

However, when executing the same (or any) command in bash, the tool works as expected.

I have been able to get the command to work by placing `alias gam="~/bin/gam/gam"` in my `.zshrc`, but this causes some unexpected issues with gam arguments beginning with `~`.

`~/bin/gam/gam` has execute privileges as well as its accompanying folder `~/bin/gam/`, so I can't figure out what's wrong here.

Comment: Try a `which gam` in zsh maybe.

Comment: `which gam` returns `gam not found`

Comment: Check your path then.

Comment: `echo $PATH` returns `/Users/dmaadmin/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS`. `gam` is at `/Users/dmaadmin/bin/gam/gam` - in other words, gam should be on my path

Comment: Then double check that `gam` is executable.

Comment: `ls -l` returns `-rwxr-xr-x  1 dmaadmin  staff  8360244 Dec 21  2017 gam` in ~/bin/gam/

Comment: Aha! You say that `/Users/dmaadmin/bin/gam/gam` should be in your path, but there is no reason it should! Only `~/bin` is in your path, not `~/bin/gam`.

Comment: Thanks! I was under the impression that including a folder in your path also meant that any subfolders would be added as well. Problem solved!

Comment: I guess calling `gam` was trying to execute the folder `~/bin/gam/`, so zsh wasn't sure what to do with it. The install script also only modified .bashrc, explaining why `gam` worked in bash but not in zsh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~/bin/` was in my `PATH` but the subfolder `~/bin/gam/` was not. Calling `gam` would cause ZSH to find the folder `~/bin/gam/` and try to execute it, hence the `permission denied` error instead of `command not found`.

The reason `gam` worked in BASH was because the install script only added `~/bin/gam/` to my `PATH` in `.bashrc` and not `.zshrc`