# ZSH: do not regard subfolders contained in folders listed in $PATH as executables

Tags: path, zsh

Can ZSH be configured so that, just like Bash, it disregards subdirectories contained in the directories listed in `$PATH`?

According to [Bart Schaefer](https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2011/msg00237.html) seemingly the subfolders contained in the folders listed in `$PATH` are handled like executables in ZSH (whereas Bash disconsiders them).

For example, if `$PATH` contains the folder `/usr/local/bin` and there is a subfolder `md5` in `/usr/local/bin` (but no such executable in a path of `$PATH` after it), then typing `md5` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> gives the response `zsh: permission denied:` (instead of `command not found` in Bash) because `md5` is not a command, but a directory.

This can bite you, for example, when a script checks  on `Linux` whether the command `md5` is available (as it is, by default on MacOS), and `zsh` wrongly returns true (the proper command would be `md5sum`). This is a frequent issue on [WSL](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3886) which converts and appends all paths in `%PATH%` to `$PATH`.

Similar questions have been asked in "[zsh: permission denied: gam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51073014/zsh-permission-denied-gam)" and "[Weird rails error "permission denied: bin/rails" for old rails apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297832/weird-rails-error-permission-denied-bin-rails-for-old-rails-apps)", but the answers did not get to the heart of the matter.

Comment: The mail you link to involves an attempt to execute an empty string as a command, not an attempt to execute a subdirectory matching the command you typed. I'm not sure how to reproduce the scenario you describe.

Comment: True, still it came closest to an explication of what is going on in contrast to how Bash handles it. Regarding reproducing the described scenario, other than the example given, there are those described in the two linked questions on this platform.

Comment: Like I said, I can't reproduce this. I have a directory `~/bin/foo`, and `~/bin` is on my path. If I try to execute `foo`, I get "command not found", not "permission denied".

Comment: Interesting. On zsh 5.6 (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu) with empty `/etc/zshenv`, `/etc/zshrc`, `/etc/zprofile`, `/etc/zlogin`, `~/.zshrc`, `~/.zshenv`, `~/.zprofile` and `~/.zlogin` the scenario persists.

Comment: OK, I am using 5.7.1. Just tried using 5.3 on another machine, and can get the "permission denied" message. I wonder if it's just been fixed in the newest version of `zsh`.

Comment: Even in 5.3, the built-in `which` command doesn't recognize the subdirectory as a command, which makes me think this really was just a bug.

Comment: Still, `whence -pm '*'` lists the subdirectory.